# iptables config blocks OpenVPN with udp error "Operation not permitted (code=1)

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables

With `iptables` cleaned out using the following, my OpenVPN client fires right up with no errors:

```bash
iptables -P INPUT   ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT  ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

As soon as I issue `iptables-restore` to load `rules.v4` [below], I get the following error:

```bash
Wed Sep 11 02:09:30 2019 UDP link local:  (not bound)
Wed Sep 11 02:09:30 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]188.120.224.182:1194

Wed Sep 11 02:09:30 2019 write UDP: Operation not permitted (code=1)
Wed Sep 11 02:09:32 2019 write UDP: Operation not permitted (code=1)
Wed Sep 11 02:09:37 2019 write UDP: Operation not permitted (code=1)
```

These configs work on an identical server with the same `iptables` version and Debian kernel:

- **`/etc/openvpn/server.conf`**

  ```bash
  client
  remote 188.120.200.100
  dev tun
  nobind
  tls-client
  ca /etc/openvpn/client/ca.crt
  cert /etc/openvpn/client/tornado.com.crt
  key /etc/openvpn/client/tornado.com.key
  comp-lzo
  log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
  verb 3
  ping-restart 10
  #ifconfig 10.9.8.2 10.9.8.1
  #persist-key
  #persist-tun
  ```
- **`/etc/iptables/rules.v4`**

  ```bash
  # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Jul 14 02:18:04 2019

  *filter
  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

  -A INPUT                  -i lo -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

  -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED       -j ACCEPT

  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED  -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED  -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED  -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m udp --sport 53   -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m tcp --sport 53   -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m tcp --sport 80   -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m tcp --sport 443  -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m udp --sport 695  -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m tcp --sport 3128 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m tcp --sport 6667 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m tcp --sport 9001 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED      -m tcp --sport 9030 -j ACCEPT

  -A INPUT -i tun0                -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG    --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: "
  -A INPUT                        -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

  -A FORWARD                -i tun0                                       -j ACCEPT
  -A FORWARD -s 10.9.8.0/24 -i tun0 -o eth0                               -j ACCEPT
  -A FORWARD                        -m state  --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  -A FORWARD -d 10.9.8.26/32 -p tcp -m tcp    --dport 80                  -j ACCEPT
  -A FORWARD                        -m limit  --limit 3/min               -j LOG    --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: "
  -A FORWARD                                                              -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

  -A OUTPUT -o lo   -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -m tcp --sport 2222 -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -m udp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -m tcp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 53   -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 53   -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 80   -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 443  -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 695  -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 6667 -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 9030 -j ACCEPT

  -A OUTPUT -o tun0                 -j ACCEPT
  -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min  -j LOG    --log-prefix "iptables_OUTPUT_denied: "
  -A OUTPUT                         -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

  COMMIT

  # Completed on Sun Jul 14 02:18:04 2019
  # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Jul 14 02:18:04 2019
  *nat
  :PREROUTING ACCEPT [4915297:1580921207]
  :INPUT ACCEPT [5132:265999]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [128157:9331722]
  :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [46763:3069634]

  -A PREROUTING                   -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80    -j DNAT --to-destination 10.9.8.26

  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.0/24  -o eth0                             -j MASQUERADE
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80    -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.206
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80    -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.207
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443   -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.206
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 695   -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.206
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128  -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.206
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6667  -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.206
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9001  -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.206
  -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.9.8.26/32 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9030  -j SNAT --to-source 188.120.231.206

  COMMIT
  # Completed on Sun Jul 14 02:18:04 2019
  ```

How do I get my config to work?

Comment: So the IPTABLES configuration blocks many outgoing ports based on source port or destination port.  You're using "nobind" in your openvpn client, which means it will select a random local port to use.  What's the destination port on the remote server?

Comment: @Iyad K  1194

but the error says (local)

Comment: Can you clarify if the IPTABLES config above is on the server or the client?  So the destination port is 1194 protocol UDP.  Maybe I missed something but your rules don't allow egress to 1194 on UDP if those rules are for a client.  This rule allows source port to be 1194 but not destination:
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m udp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT .   
This rule rejects everything that isn't in the list of approved rules:
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Comment: @lyad L that is a server firewall config

Comment: @Iyad K I tried to comment out the line with  REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable and then iptables-restore, same issue.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your openvpn instance is acting as a client (even if the conf file is named "server.conf").

In order to get it work, you need to remove the nobind parameter from the configuration file.

Comment: The OP stated it was a client config, and it's more than just that one line that makes it a client config: `client` and `tls-client` do as well.